# Почему возникает ошибка segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linux

Хочу динамически выделить память и записать туда некий буфер по указателю, в данном случае строку:

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *a = (char*) malloc(6*sizeof(char));
    char *str="Hello";
    *a=*str;
    printf ("%s\n", *a);
    free (a);

return   0;
}
```

Но компилятор выдает ошибку. В чем я неправ? Как использовать динамически выделенную память? `Strcpy`?
Ошибка возникает при использовании `printf`.

Есть у меня еще программа, но там другой компилятор, не gcc. При таком коде тоже возникает ошибка:

```
char *array = (char*)malloc(6*sizeof(char));
array= "Hello";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В этой программе

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *a = (char*) malloc(6*sizeof(char));
    char *str="Hello";
    *a=*str;
    printf ("%s\n", *a);
    free (a);

return   0;
}
```

вы сначала динамически выделяете память под символьный массив

```
    char *a = (char*) malloc(6*sizeof(char));
```

Следовательно указатель `a` теперь содержит адрес первого байта этого  участка памяти.

Затем вы присваиваете первый символ строкового литерала `"Hello"` первому байту памяти, адресуемой указателем `a`

```
    *a=*str;
```

Теперь у вас в выделенной памяти содержится

```
'H' и некоторый "мусор"
```

Так как остальные байты выделенной памяти не были инициализированы.

В функции `printf` вы используете спецификатор формата `%s`, который предполагает, что соответствующий аргумент является строкой, то есть символьным массивом, имеющем завершающий нулевой символ `'\0'`.

Однако ваша строка не содержит завершающий ноль. Поэтому данная функция пытается вывести на консоль все символы даже за пределом выделенного вами участка памяти, пока не встретит символ завершения строки `'\0'`.

В результате вы получаете ошибку сегментации памяти.

Более того вы в качестве аргумента указали этот первый символ строки вместо адреса

```
printf ("%s\n", *a);
                ^^^
```

Должно быть по крайней мере

```
printf ("%s\n", a);
                ^^
```

Что касается данного фрагмента кода

```
char *array = (char*)malloc(6*sizeof(char));
array= "Hello";
```

То, во-первых, здесь имеет место "утечка" памяти. Вы сначала выделили динамически память и ее адрес присвоили указателю `array`. А затем этому указателю же присвоили адрес строкового литерала (его первого символа). В результате адрес выделенной динамически памяти был утерян.

Для этого фрагмента кода причиной ошибки скорей всего является то, что вы пытались освободить память с помощью функции `free`, записав

```
free( array );
```

В этом случае функция будет пытаться удалить статическую память, занимаемую строковым литералом, так как в данный момент `array` указывает на строковый литерал. Однако нельзя удалять статическую память с помощью функции `free`, так как эта память не была выделена динамически. ее зарезервировал компилятор еще во время компиляции, когда встретил в вашей программе строковый литерал. Это - та память, которая освобождается системой после завершения работы программы.

Правильно было бы написать

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char *array = (char*)malloc(6*sizeof(char));
strcpy( array, "Hello" );

//...

free( array );
```

И в первой программе вместо

```
    *a=*str;
```

вам следует написать

```
    strcpy( a, str );
```

предварительно включив заголовок `<string.h>`

Comment: @BOPOH  Это я допустил ошибку, не обратив внимание, что  указатели разыменовываются в предложении *a = *str; .:) Я исправил свой ответ.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!!!

Comment: @MaximGusev Не за что. Я еще дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: При изменении второй и третей строк в функции main, segmentation fault не исчезает.. char *str = "Hello\0";  strcpy(a, str); В чем я еще не прав..?( Насколько я знаю, компилятор в таких случаях сам ведь добавляет нуль-терминированную строку?

Comment: @MaximGusev Извините, я проглядел. Уберите разыменование указателя в printf. Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Я очень благодарен Вам!

Comment: @MaximGusev, в последнем примере можно получить тот же результат совсем просто: `char *array = strdup("Hello");`